# Get ping from Twilio Video Java

Tags: java, android, twilio

Is it possible to receive information about the ping, at the time of using the Programmable Video service? Thank you.

I need the ability to tell the user that the delay between sending and receiving video has increased. For example, if the delay is half a second, the green indicator is displayed, if the second is yellow, more than a second is red. Is it possible to do this using the built-in Twilio functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure what you mean by the ping, in the context of Programmable Video.

My guess is that you want to test the connection. That's not possible before a call has connected, because WebRTC is peer to peer. The connection is direct between the clients (unless you are using group rooms).

You can detect the quality of the connection using the stats methods in the SDK once you are connected though, check out the [`getStats` method on the `Room` class](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/video/releases/1.3.2/docs/com/twilio/video/Room.html#getStats-com.twilio.video.StatsListener-).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I need the ability to tell the user that the delay between sending and receiving video has increased. For example, if the delay is half a second, the green indicator is displayed, if the second is yellow, more than a second is red. Is it possible to do this using the built-in Twilio functionality?

Comment: This isn't built in Twilio functionality, rather it's built in WebRTC functionality. Looks like you can get an estimated [round trip time](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcoutboundrtpstreamstats-roundtriptime) which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you